# How do I find the tangent slope function of a reciprocal function?

Tags: calculus

Up until now, I've been finding tangent slope functions I've just been using this with formula with the given function:

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Which have worked fine so far for regular quadratic and cubic functions. However, I'm not sure how to do it with a reciprocal function, for example $y=\frac{1}{x-1}$

When I try, I just end up doing this:

$\frac{\frac{1}{(x+h)-1}-\frac{1}{x-1}}{h}$

And from there I have no idea how to derive the function into one with only integers, x's and h's, and no fractions (which with I let $h=0$ to find the tangent slope function).

How can I find the tangent slope function for these types of functions?

Comment: The tangent slope function of a reciprocal function is equal to 1/(the tangent slope of the function)

Comment: Well, you'll have to deal with fractions, I'm afraid...not big deal in some cases, though.

Comment: No @JJacquelin, it is not. The slope at $\;x=1\;$ of $\;1/x\;$ is **not** $\;1/1=1\;$ ...!

Comment: Well, it's alright if the resulting function is still in fractions, but my problem is that I have no idea how to find that resulting function. How do I proceed after I have set it up like this: 
$$\frac{\frac{1}{(x+h)-1}-\frac{1}{x-1}}{h}$$

Comment: @ DonAntonio :  You make a confusion. Your example $f(x)=1/x$ The slope at $x=1$ is $-1$. So, we expect for the reciprocal function the slope = $1/(-1)=-1$. The reciprocal function is $x=1/f$ . At $f=1$ the slope is $-1$ . That's correct.

Comment: No @JJacquelin: if what you wrote were true, then the slope of the reciprocal of $\;f(x)=x\;$ , i.e. of $\;1/x\;$ would be the reciprocal of the slope of $\;f(x)=x\;$ at any point (say, at any point...where the reciprocal is still defined)...and it is not.

Comment: And even if you start with $\;1/x\;$ , the slope of this function at $\;x=1\;$ is $\;-1\;$ , and the slope of its reciprocal **at the same point** $\;x=1\;$ is $\;1\neq \frac{1}{-1}\;$ ...

Comment: @ DonAntonio : In fact there is a mess due to the definitions of the "reciprocal function" and the "inverse function". You are right with the English définitions. I am not English, so I missunderstood the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Definition of "inverse" : 
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_inverse . Définition of "reciprocal" :http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_r%C3%A9ciproque.

Comment: Yeah: the french have the names all messed up. It's astonishing how the've managed, and still do manage, to make superb mathematics. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example (which, btw, has a mistake in your last mathematical expression...):

$$\frac{\frac1{x+h-1}-\frac1{x-1}}{h}=\frac{-\color{red}h}{\color{red}h(x+h-1)(x-1)}\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{}\frac{-1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: What's the mistake? And how did you go from $\frac{\frac1{x+h-1}-\frac1{x-1}}{h}$ to $\frac{-h}{h(x+h-1)(x-1)}$?

Comment: @Threethumb, that's just high school algebra. In the numerator we have: $$\frac1{x+h-1}-\frac1{x-1}=\frac{x-1-(x+h-1)}{(x+h-1)(x-1)}=\frac{-h}{(x+h-1)(x-1)}\ldots$$

Comment: And the mistake was in the OP, where in the last expression's first summand you had $\;\frac1{x+h}\;$ instead of $\;\frac1{x+h-1}\;$ . Now it's fine.

Comment: Well, this *is* a high school course, which I'm doing after not having touched math for 4 years. Pardon me if I'm rusty at this. Using the form of Gerry: $${A\over B}+{C\over D}$$

I don't really understand why it works to create a new expression that is $\frac{D-B}{B*D}$. I can see that's what you're doing, but it doesn't strike me as the natural thing to do, seeing as I don't understand why that method works. Could you explain why it works to do this?

Comment: Common divisor, @Threethumb . As Gerry wrote: for general fractions, we have $$\frac ab\pm \frac cd=\frac{ad\pm bc}{bd}$$ The doble sign means it doesn't matter whether it is plus or minus. This is precisely what I wrote about three comments above. After that, you have an expression of the form $$\frac{\frac ab}{c}=\frac a{bc}$$

Comment: Okay, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

What you may be missing is that you can simplify an expression of the form $${A\over B}+{C\over D}\over E$$ by multiplying numerator and denominator by $BD$.